# How to give a permanent dns subdomain for a new ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

After an Amazon EC2 instanced is created, is it possible to give it an address like subdomain1.example.com

Domain example.com is a domain purchased through route53.

I search the amazon forums but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the word permanent from your question and just go to your domain in Route53.

Add example1 as an A record pointing to the elastic IP you have in front of your EC2 machine.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html